# Typescript pass enum class constructor argument

Tags: typescript

Most likely it must be a very simple issue, but i can't understand why i can't initialize a class instance with enum parameter.

Error: `Argument type {type: MessageTypes} is not assignable to parameter type MessageTypes`

**class:**

```
export enum MessageTypes {
  STATUS,
  CONTROL
}
export enum MessageStatus {
  OK,
  ERROR
}
export enum MessageCommands {
  REQUEST_STATUS_ALL
}


export class Message {
  type: MessageTypes;
  status?: MessageStatus;
  command?: MessageCommands;
  body?: any;

  constructor(type: MessageTypes, command?: MessageCommands, status?: MessageStatus, body?: any) {
    this.type = type;
    this.status = status;
    this.command = command;
    this.body = body;
  }
}
```

usage:
`const msg = new Message({type: MessageTypes.CONTROL});`

Comment: You're passing an object containing the enum, not an enum.  Change it to `new Message(MessageTypes.CONTROL)` or change your constructor to take an object.

Comment: oh right. but how can i pass only a few params then? (in case i dont pass an object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want your constructor to accept an object containing a `type` property:

```
constructor(settings : { type: MessageTypes, command?: MessageCommands, status?: MessageStatus, body?: any}) {
    this.type = settings.type;
    this.status = settings.status;
    this.command = settings.command;
    this.body = settings.body;
}
```

Either that or don't pass in an object, and just pass the type as the first argument.

```
const msg = new Message(MessageTypes.CONTROL);
```

If you want to skip some of the arguments, you can just pass in `null` or `undefined` for the arguments that you don't need:

```
const msg = new Message(MessageTypes.CONTROL, null, MessageStatus.OK)
```

Comment: `new Message(MessageTypes.CONTROL);` but in this case there is no way to skip an argument, right?

Comment: @user1935987 The other arguments are optional, so they can be skipped.

Comment: but they are positional, so i can't for example do this `new Message(MessageTypes.CONTROL, body);`

Comment: @user1935987 You can fill the blank ones with `null` or `undefined`: `new Message(MessageTypes.CONTROL, null, null, "body")`

Comment: ah, thats it! thanks! please add that to the answer, might be useful